# Indexed search displays html and js-code typo3

Tags: search, typo3, indexed

I've upgraded from 4.2 to 4.5 in single upgrades (4.2->4.3 etc.). After the final upgrade, the indexed search displays the html and js code of some content blocks in the search results. Not all though. I can't find a pattern for that. I moved the HTML block to the bottom, in case it now simply displays the top most block, I emptied all tables that start with index_ to make sure it renders the index new, i emptied my browser's cache, it still displays html and js code.

I compared it to a node, that is displayed correctly as a result, the html block is top most, the code is the same, just two pictures were added for a image slider, Access and Appearance have the same settings.

Any idea what's causing that behavior? someone experienced the same thing?

Comment: i've found out, some of the entries will display correct, if i delete the "-" in linked image names. But other entries don't have a "-" inside the js code. Entering working js code in their html-content-element won't work. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Does HTML code is valid ? Probably, parser couldn't interpret it because of corrupted strcture ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer and sorry for the trouble.. (just to make this complete, yes, HTML was valid.)

I did not quite found out why this search-thing occurs, but I managed to find a workaround by extracting the JS in a seperate .js-file, and call it within the script-tags. I expected it to don't display any teaser at all, but it displayed to real content instead. No idea why that happened, but I can suppress it like that. Maybe that will help somebody else too..